# JSON variable not read as text

Tags: xml, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to learn from someone's code who has a xml processing function that does this:

```
$(xml).find("page").find("user").each(function(){
...
    var user = $(this);         
    var userId = $(user).find("Id").text();
...
    MAP.setMarkerClickListener(TRACKER.users[userId].mapMarker[0].marker,function (){
        MAP.openInfoWindow(TRACKER.users[userId].mapMarker[0].infoWindow, TRACKER.users[userId].mapMarker[0].marker);   
    });
```

Works great, however I was building an application using JSON and I try to do something similar with:

```
for (var i=0; i<json.users.length; i++) {
    var user = json.users[i];
...
    MAP.setMarkerClickListener(TRACKER.users[user.id].mapMarker.marker,function(){
        MAP.openInfoWindow(TRACKER.users[user.id].mapMarker.infoWindow, TRACKER.users[user.id].mapMarker.marker);   
    });
```

I think the problem is the original's XML's text was passed into the function. In mine, the variable is being passed in and therefore the last value the variable holds in the value the function uses. I've tried to JSON.stringify the variable into a new variable, but it did not work.

Mine successfully adds a listener to every marker, however they call execute the function as if they were the last marker.

Any ideas how to make this work with JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be JSON data not valid
Can you show a JSON response data.

the way to loop json data should be this

```
$.each(json.users,function(key,data){
  ...
  MAP.setMarkerClickListener(TRACKER.users[data.id].mapMarker.marker,function(){
   MAP.openInfoWindow(TRACKER.users[data.id].mapMarker.infoWindow, TRACKER.users[data.id].mapMarker.marker);   
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, that's so weird. I saw the for loop method on many sites and a few claimed it as the elegant way to go about it. Changing this instantly worked. Thank you greatly.